# how to add array of text to multiple divs with d3

Tags: d3.js

```js
var dataArray=[20,40,50,60,70,80,90];
d3.select("body")
    .selectAll(".small-div")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter()
    .append("span")
    .text(function(d){
      return d;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

I have created the above set of code to add the data array to the div elements with class="small-div". The code is not working, please give any solution

Comment: Click "run code snippet": you'll see that it is "working" (by the way, it doesn't create any div element). What's the exact problem here? If the divs already exist in your HTML, just drop the `enter()`.

Comment: divs are already existing and I just want to add text to those existing divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is just this line:

```
.enter()
```

In D3, this is one of the most famous methods. It...

> Returns the enter selection: placeholder nodes for each datum that had **no corresponding DOM element** in the selection. (emphasis mine)

So, if you already have the `<div>`s in the page, your "enter" selection will be empty!

Let's prove it:

```js
var dataArray = [20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90];
var selection = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(".small-div")
  .data(dataArray)
  .enter();
  
//nothing will be appended here!
selection.append("span")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
  
console.log("the size of the enter selection is: " + selection.size())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="small-div"></div>
<div class="small-div"></div>
<div class="small-div"></div>
<div class="small-div"></div>
<div class="small-div"></div>
<div class="small-div"></div>
<div class="small-div"></div>
```

As you can see, nothing happens, no element is appended (and the message in the console is pretty clear).

However, if we simply drop the `enter()`, the data will be bound to the existing DOM elements, and you'll have what we call an "update" selection. Now you're appending the `<span>` elements to a selection which is not empty.

Have a look:

```js
var dataArray = [20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90];
d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(".small-div")
  .data(dataArray)
  .append("span")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="small-div"></div>
<div class="small-div"></div>
<div class="small-div"></div>
<div class="small-div"></div>
<div class="small-div"></div>
<div class="small-div"></div>
<div class="small-div"></div>
```